# Scale pygal svg graphs in web page with susy

Tags: css, svg, susy, pygal

I am trying to place two svg files side by side in a web page.  This I have done using susy to create the spans, first one is 2 columns wide, the second 10 columns.  I place a narrow bar graph in the first span, and a wide line graph in the second span.

The problem I am having is scaling the graphs. they look like this:
[image]

But I want them to look more like this:
[image]

They are svg files generated with pygal and I achieved the second image by forcing a size in pygal, but it's not elegant and fails wehn the screen size changes.

How can I make the svg bar chart scale the height without scaling the width and do it dynamically in a web browser instead of manually changing the size in pygal?  I also cant manually edit the svg files as they are generated via another system and update frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphs should load in two different divs, so that you can set a different `width` style for each, depending on a view-based css class (like `col` based classes in Twitter Bootstrap). If you load dynamic svg's (without any `explicit_size` setting in Pygal) you should be able to handle different window sizes.